# Can't get my equation to work properly

Tags: c++

I've created a program for my final to calculate the wilks coefficient and some other things for a powerlifting meet. I can't get the equation to output anything correctly. I've tried to manipulate my parenthesis but I'm still stuck.

This is the equation in question, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilks_Coefficient#Equation

And a functioning calculator for reference
http://www.lift.net/wilks-calculator/

```
while (gender == "female")
    {
        cout << "Please use kilograms (KG) for all inputs." << endl;
        cout << "Enter your bodyweight: ";
        cin >> weight;
        cout << "Enter your final bench press attempt: ";
        cin >> bench;
        cout << "Enter your final squat attempt: ";
        cin >> squat;
        cout << "Enter your final deadlift attempt: ";
        cin >> deadlift;

        total = bench + squat + deadlift;

        wilks = total / A_WOMEN + B_WOMEN * (weight) + C_WOMEN * (weight * weight) + D_WOMEN * (weight * weight * weight) +
            E_WOMEN * (weight * weight * weight * weight) + F_WOMEN * (weight * weight * weight * weight * weight);

        cout << wilks;
        cout << endl;
    }

    while (gender == "male")
    {
        cout << "Please use kilograms (KG) for all inputs." << endl;
        cout << "Enter your bodyweight: ";
        cin >> weight;
        cout << "Enter your final bench press attempt: ";
        cin >> bench;
        cout << "Enter your final squat attempt: ";
        cin >> squat;
        cout << "Enter your final deadlift attempt: ";
        cin >> deadlift;

        total = bench + squat + deadlift;

        wilks = total / A_MEN + B_MEN * (weight) + ((C_MEN) * (weight * weight)) + ((D_MEN) * (weight * weight * weight)) +
            E_MEN * (weight * weight * weight * weight) + ((F_MEN) * (weight * weight * weight * weight * weight));

        cout << wilks;
        cout << endl;
    }
```

Comment: split the formula (there is no equation in that code, but only an assignment) into several small pieces. And provide a mcve (google it if you dont know what this is). What is the type of all this variables?

Comment: `total/A_MEN + B_MEN * (weight) + ...` You need another pair of parentheses here.

Comment: They are all doubles. I haven't learned what a "mcve" is yet.

Comment: I see your problem...  `A_WOMEN` and friends are not defined.

Comment: I can't see your entire comment n.m.

Comment: This isn't the problem, but look at all the identical code in the two loops. That **strongly** suggests that the code should be refactored. Write a function that takes a flag that indicates which set of constants to use, and put all that duplicated code into the function.

Comment: Okay, thanks to you all for your help. I swapped out the total variable to '500' in the equation and created another variable to store the actual wilks number, wilks = wilksCalc * total; Obviously, I didn't understand equation. @Pete.Becker I would love to do that as it sounds way more efficient and I'm sure my teacher would like that but I don't know how to "Write a function that takes a flag that indicates which set of constants to use", can you give me a push in the right direction on that one?

Comment: The reason I have my code structured is so is because we MUST use a sentinel controlled while-loop, to which I've been taught that I need ONE input first to control the while loop and then include the any other inputs inside the loops.

Answer (score 2):

I would do

```
wilks = total / (A_WOMEN + B_WOMEN * (weight) + C_WOMEN * (weight * weight) + D_WOMEN * (weight * weight * weight) +
            E_WOMEN * (weight * weight * weight * weight) + F_WOMEN * (weight * weight * weight * weight * weight));
```

That is, enclosing with `()` the denominator (for both male and female).

Answer (score 1):

Due to operator precedence, the expression

```
total / A_WOMEN +
B_WOMEN * (weight) +
C_WOMEN * (weight * weight) +
D_WOMEN * (weight * weight * weight) +
E_WOMEN * (weight * weight * weight * weight) +
F_WOMEN * (weight * weight * weight * weight * weight);
```

Is equivalent to:

```
t1 + t2 + t3 + t4 + t5 + t6
```

where

```
t1 = total / A_WOMEN +
t2 = B_WOMEN * (weight) +
t3 = C_WOMEN * (weight * weight) +
t4 = D_WOMEN * (weight * weight * weight) +
t5 = E_WOMEN * (weight * weight * weight * weight) +
t6 = F_WOMEN * (weight * weight * weight * weight * weight);
```

That explains why you are getting the wrong results.

---

What you need is

```
t1 = A_WOMEN 
t2 = B_WOMEN * (weight) 
t3 = C_WOMEN * (weight * weight) 
t4 = D_WOMEN * (weight * weight * weight) 
t5 = E_WOMEN * (weight * weight * weight * weight) 
t6 = F_WOMEN * (weight * weight * weight * weight * weight)

den = t1 + t2 + t3 + t4 + t5 + t6
wilks = total/den
```

It's better to write unambiguous and simpler code than to write hard to understand long expressions.

Also, you have the same code for receiving input and computing the coefficient for both men and women. It will be better create two functions - one to get the input and one to compute the coefficient. Then call the functions appropriately.

```
// Function to get input from user
std::pair<double, double> getInput()
{
   double weight;
   double bench;
   double squat;
   double deadlift;

   cout << "Please use kilograms (KG) for all inputs." << endl;
   cout << "Enter your bodyweight: ";
   cin >> weight;
   cout << "Enter your final bench press attempt: ";
   cin >> bench;
   cout << "Enter your final squat attempt: ";
   cin >> squat;
   cout << "Enter your final deadlift attempt: ";
   cin >> deadlift;

   return std::make_pair(weight, bench + squat + deadlift);
}
```

---

```
// Function to compute the Wilks coefficient.
double getWilksCoefficient(double weight,
                           double total,
                           A_COEFF,
                           B_COEFF,
                           C_COEFF,
                           D_COEFF,
                           E_COEFF,
                           F_COEFF)
{
    double t1 = A_COEFF;
    double t2 = B_COEFF * (weight);
    double t3 = C_COEFF * (weight * weight);
    double t4 = D_COEFF * (weight * weight * weight);
    double t5 = E_COEFF * (weight * weight * weight * weight);
    double t6 = F_COEFF * (weight * weight * weight * weight * weight);

    double den = t1 + t2 + t3 + t4 + t5 + t6;
    return total/den;
}
```

---

```
// Use the above functions and reduce duplicate code.
std::pair<double, double> input = getInput();

// "while" does not make sense. "if" makes sense.
// while (gender == "female")
if (gender == "female")
{
   wilks = getWilksCoefficient(input.first,
                               input.second,
                               A_WOMEN,
                               B_WOMEN,
                               C_WOMEN,
                               D_WOMEN,
                               E_WOMEN,
                               F_WOMEN);

}

// Can "gender" be anything other than male or female?
// else if (gender == "male")
else
{
   wilks = getWilksCoefficient(input.first,
                               input.second,
                               A_MEN,
                               B_MEN,
                               C_MEN,
                               D_MEN,
                               E_MEN,
                               F_MEN);
}

cout << wilks;
cout << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

First, the coefficient has 500 in the numerator, not the total weight lifted.

You then multiply the total lifted weight with the coefficient to get some kind of standardised amount lifted.

I would write

```
wilks = 500.0 / (a + weight * (b + weight * (c + weight * (d + weight * (e + weight * f)))));
```

if it's the coefficient you want.
Multiply by the total lifted weight if that's the value you're after.

Side note:
Inserting parentheses at random rarely does any good.
If you're not familiar with the precedence of different operators - `x / a + b` is not `x / (a + b)` but `(x / a) + b` - now is the time to break out your old maths book from primary school.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the algorithm. Make sure you use `double` for everything since you're using real numbers. And I have no idea why you're using a while for `male` vs. `female`. Use an if/else statement instead:

```
    if (gender == "female")
    {
        cout << "Please use kilograms (KG) for all inputs." << endl;
        cout << "Enter your bodyweight: ";
        cin >> weight;
        cout << "Enter your final bench press attempt: ";
        cin >> bench;
        cout << "Enter your final squat attempt: ";
        cin >> squat;
        cout << "Enter your final deadlift attempt: ";
        cin >> deadlift;

        total = bench + squat + deadlift;

        double coeff = 500.0 / ((A_WOMEN) + (B_WOMEN * weight) + (C_WOMEN * square(weight)) + (D_WOMEN * pow(weight, 3)) + (E_WOMEN * pow(weight, 4)) + (F_WOMEN * pow(weight, 5)));
        wilks = coeff * total;

        cout << wilks;
        cout << endl;
    }
    else // gender == "male")
    {
        cout << "Please use kilograms (KG) for all inputs." << endl;
        cout << "Enter your bodyweight: ";
        cin >> weight;
        cout << "Enter your final bench press attempt: ";
        cin >> bench;
        cout << "Enter your final squat attempt: ";
        cin >> squat;
        cout << "Enter your final deadlift attempt: ";
        cin >> deadlift;

        total = bench + squat + deadlift;

        double coeff = 500.0 / ((A_MEN) + (B_MEN * weight) + (C_MEN * square(weight)) + (D_MEN * pow(weight, 3)) + (E_MEN * pow(weight, 4)) + (F_MEN * pow(weight, 5)));
        wilks = coeff * total;

        cout << wilks;
        cout << endl;
    }
```

Comment: Why do you have the same input code in both sections?  You should refactor the code so that common input is performed before the gender check.

Comment: Also, if you are going to write code for people, please indicate how your code differs from the OP's code.

Comment: Both good comments. I should have seen the refactor opportunity. Was trying to get an answer in before 50 other people answered instead of me. :/